# Modification to reduce execution time

Tags: java

i have completed this code but this code is executing very slow please tell me how to fast execution time or what is the modification in coding
(This program save prime numbers between 500000 to 10000000 in task text file)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class primenumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintStream as = new PrintStream("task.txt");
        int i,j,k;
        for(i=500000;i<10000000;i++) //here you can give your own range
        {
            k=0;
            for(j=2;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                    k++;
            }
            if(k==0)
                as.println(i+" ");
        }
        as.close();
        System.out.println("file is created");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient method to find out prime numbers. Use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or another method to spot them.

Comment: please some explain me how to use sieve of Eratosthenes method i am beginner not understand it

Comment: Well the sieve makes use of the integer factorization property: any integer can be seen as the multiplication of prime numbers (for a prime, exactly one). Thus there is no use in checking for `%6`, since the `%2` and `%3` will have failed first. The sieve test thus filters all integers that fail the already found prime numbers away.

Answer (score 2):

I won't tell you to use a faster algorithm, you'll probably have a lot of other (better explained) suggestions for that.

I'll stick with optimizing your inner for loop: **you can stop your inner for loop as soon as you know `i` isn't a prime**

```
boolean isPrime = true;
for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isPrime)
    as.println(i + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The method to calculate prime numbers is very inefficient.

First you don't have to count the number of dividers, from the moment there is one, you can skip that number.

Second, you can stop at **sqrt(n)** since all dividers over sqrt(n) have another co-divider that is smaller...

As @eldjon points out, one can also skip all even numbers (start with an odd number and increment with 2).

Finally, you don't need to enumerate over **all** numbers, all found prime numbers less than **sqrt(n)** are sufficient.

As @LuiggiMendoza points out, you can indeed improve the speed of writing prime numbers to a file as well. If the file is not required to be textual, one can even better write the integers binary (since there is no computational cost in converting them, and integers will be stored more efficiently).

There is of course the fast prime check that takes `log`-time (Agrawal, *Primes is in P*), but this is a quite complicated algorithm.

---

Proposed faster algorithm (not taking into account older prime numbers):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class primenumber {

    public static boolean checkDiv (int n) {
        int s = (int) Math.sqrt(n)+1;
        for(int i = 2; i < s; i++) {
            if((n%i) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintStream as = new PrintStream("task.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int low = 500000;
        int high = 10000000;
        for(int i=low|1;i<high;i += 2) {
            if(checkDiv(i)) {
                sb.append(i+"\n");
            }
        }
        as.println(sb.toString());
        as.close();
        System.out.println("file is created");
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/9f)

Comment: Also, apart from improving the algorithm to verify if the number is prime, I would use a `StringBuilder` to store the results and append a single *big* `String` into the `PrintStream`.

Comment: Normally a `PrintStream` will not write content to the file directly I guess. They normally use some kind of "flush" approach...

Comment: Yes, it will happen on a `flush` and it automatically happens when calling `close`. But in case of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), this happens everytime you call `println` method: *Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the `println` methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written*. But this doesn't seem to affect `PrintStream`s created for files.

Comment: Well, in a matter of fact, the question is all about improving prime number search algorithm, and other secondary operations are to no importance.

Comment: @MeiravLeibowitz: Yes but eventually, you do something with those numbers: store them in an array, write them to a file. Thus Luiggi Mendoza's point was valid.

Comment: Then if this is true, then it's better to open the file at the end (this part needs to be improved) after calculating the primes, not to busy out the memory during all the calculatios, and close it direcly after it (this part is done).

Comment: text file is not proper formated please tell how include new line option after on entry

Comment: Well replace `" "` with `"\n"`, (I don't see why you add a backspace at the end of a line).

Answer (score 1):

Update below loop to use sqrt method:

```
int jMax = (int) Math.sqrt(i);
for(j=2;j<=jMax;j++)
```

Comment: I would advice calculating `Math.Sqrt(i)` once, since this is an "expensive" computation.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple modification i would add to your `for` loop (or to other suggested answers as well)  is to go through only odd numbers. we know for sure that even numbers (except 2) cannot be prime. So this would reduce the number of iterations by 50%:

```
for(int i=500001;i<10000000;i+=2)
```

And secondly save the result into memory (into an array for example) and store at once the entire result list to the file. A single access to memory is more efficient than your `for` loop.